# open .txt file which is stored in mysql

Tags: php

I am trying to open a .txt file which is stored im mysql. May be the problem is too small but I am just stuck here. here is the script and please anyone guide me.

```
$connect = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', 'password') or die(mysql_error());
$select_db = mysql_select_db('uploadFile', $connect) or die(mysql_error());
$file = $_FILES['file']['name'];
$fileType = $_FILES['file']['type'];
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], 'txt_files/'. $file);
$query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO file VALUES ('$file')") or die(mysql_error());
$selectQuery = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM file");
```

I lost my 3 days searching for it. Please guide me. Thanks

Comment: Please do not use mysql. Use **mysqli** or **PDO** instead

Answer (score 0):

your file path is store in mysql and file is copied in txt_files folder, check your txt_files folder if file succesfully upload then it is on that folder